# Include more controllers into a single page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just started learning Laravel, and I want to include a second controller into my main layout.

The route is the default root directory: `/`

And the layout looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>
<div class="basket">
    ~basket comes here~
</div>
```

I want to show the user's basket, but I need DB queries for that, and I can't find a way to include an other controller, atleast not with routing.

I'm not really asking for code (Sadly i didn't find a better place for this question), probably I just need a designing tip, I really feel I'm trying to do it wrong, since I couldn't find any relevant/helpful information for this.

And I dont want to put the basket into every controller that uses my `main` layout.

Any kind of help would be apreciated, I'm really lost :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers). Open you *AppServiceProvider* and inside the *boot()* method add the following:

```
view()->composer('your.layout.name', function ($view) {
    $basket = ...// Your basket query here

    $view->with('basket', basket);
});
```

This basically says, when view with name *your.layout.name* is composed, add variable with name *$basket*.

Comment: I actually read the laravel docs, and I don't know how did I miss this! Thanks for your answer, exactly what i was looking for.